# Converting table into a list in R

Tags: r, list, aggregate

**Suppose I have a dataframe like this:**

| ID | Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2/2/20 | 1 |
| 102 | 2/2/20 | 1 |
| 103 | 2/2/20 | 1 |
| 104 | 2/2/20 | 2 |
| 105 | 2/2/20 | 2 |
| 106 | 2/2/20 | 2 |

**I want to convert it into a table that looks like this:**

| Status | ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101,102,103 | 2/2/20, 2/2/20, 2/2/20 |
| 1 | 104,105,106 | 2/2/20, 2/2/20, 2/2/20 |

I am trying to use lapply and aggregate but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Code that i'm currently using:

note: date is in format yyyy-mm-dd before running code.

```
g1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = '%Y%m%d')) %>%
  group_by(status) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("ID", "Date"), list)
```

This seems to work except for the date in the new table is not in yyyy-mm-dd. For example, 2021-06-10 is converting to 18788.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, create use the formula method (`.` - selects all columns other than the grouping column 'Status') and specify the function as `list`

```
aggregate(.~ Status, df1, list)
```

-output

```
  Status            ID                   Date
1      1 101, 102, 103 2/2/20, 2/2/20, 2/2/20
2      2 104, 105, 106 2/2/20, 2/2/20, 2/2/20
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = '%m/%d/%y')) %>%
   group_by(Status) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), list), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Status ID        Date      
  <chr>  <list>    <list>    
1 1      <int [3]> <date [3]>
2 2      <int [3]> <date [3]>
> out$Date
[[1]]
[1] "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02"

[[2]]
[1] "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02"
> str(out)
tibble [2 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Status: chr [1:2] "1" "2"
 $ ID    :List of 2
  ..$ : int [1:3] 101 102 103
  ..$ : int [1:3] 104 105 106
 $ Date  :List of 2
  ..$ : Date[1:3], format: "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02"
  ..$ : Date[1:3], format: "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02" "2020-02-02"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 101:106, Date = c("2/2/20", "2/2/20", "2/2/20", 
"2/2/20", "2/2/20", "2/2/20"), Status = c("1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That seems to work for the most part but the date format seems to change when it turns into a list. I would like it to continue being in 2021-11-12 format. Is that possible?

Comment: @JohnTayson your original column 'Date' is not the `Date` class format.  If you need to convert then use `df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")` before using aggregate to convert to list columns.  Also, I assume it is month/day/year.  If it is day/month/year, the format is `%d/%m/%y`

Comment: @JohnTayson if you use the `dplyr` approach in my post, it will keep the `Date` class in the format.  with `aggregate`, there is some intrinsic coersion to its integer storage mode

Comment: Hi! Still trying to play around with your code. For some reason, the date format continues to be an issue. Will keep trying

Comment: @JohnTayson I don't see an issue in the dplyr code.  which returns a list and the class as you mentioned

Comment: What's happening is, when i run the code, instead of 2021-06-10, I'm getting 18788.

Comment: @JohnTayson I already showed the input data, and the output (`out`) I got with the `str` and extracted output as a reproducible example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245499/discussion-between-john-tayson-and-akrun).